# How to extend time in database with Laravel 5.6 post method

Tags: php, datetime, post, laravel-5

In database I've got column called 'expiration', which type is DateTime, and so values are like "2018-06-10 01:00:05".

In laravel 5.6 im working on form, by which sending Im about to extend time in database by for example 10 seconds.

What I've got at the moment is:

1) Form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/addbid', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
   <input type="hidden" name="value" value="60">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $data->id }}">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add bid</button>
   <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-danger">Go back</a>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

2) And function in my controller

```
public function addbid(Request $request)
{
    $id = Input::only('id');
    $time = Input::only('value');
    $post = Auction::where('id', $id);
    $post -> expiration += $request-> $time;
    $post -> save();
    return redirect()->route('auctions.list');
}
```

3) Post data

```
value   "60"
id      "3"
```

4) Error which occurs

```
"Unsupported operand types"
```

I'd be really thankful for any advices as I'm struggling with this problem for quite a lot time.

Comment: I see that using code below, changing value works, but that's not what I'm thinking about:

Comment: public function addbid(Request $request)
    {
        $id = Input::only('id');
        $post = Auction::where('id', $id)->first();
        $post -> expiration = '2018-06-11 17:25:30';
        $post -> save();
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Operation Successful !');
    }